# Speed Up Bond Duration Computation

Tags: r, performance, large-data, duration

Cheers,

I am using BondVal.Price from the BondValuation package to compute durations for a large number of bond trades (10 million).

`out <- in %>% group_by(cusip,trade) %>% mutate(duration = BondVal.Price(YtM = yield, SETT = execution_date, Em = OFFERING_DATE, Mat = MATURITY, CpY = freq, Coup = COUPON, DCC = dcc)$ModDUR.inYears)`

This seems to be slow; I am wondering if there is a faster way--different library or better code--to accomplish this.

Thanks for all your input and help!!

Comment: Is this an `R` package? If so, you should add that tag, you'll get a better response that way.

Comment: Thank you. I just did.

The question is related to the R package ‘BondValuation’ described here [link](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3292955) but it is also broader as there are other packages that probably could work too.